# Batch file to copy specific folders

Tags: batch-file, xcopy

This is the batch file i have created which copy the specific folders which i want. I use the specific server folder name of which i want to copy. If any changes you suggest, it will be very helpful to me. thank you.

This is my code:

```
@echo off
:: variables
echo This script takes the backup of file SwiftALM Important folders
set /P source=Enter source folder Example D:\jboss6.1\server\swift:
set /P destination=Enter Destination folder:
set /P Folder=Enter Folder name:
@echo folder=%folder%
mkdir %destination%\%folder%
set xcopy=xcopy /E/V/Q/F/H/I 
echo echo conf folder will be copied
%xcopy% %source%\conf %destination%\%folder%\conf
echo conf folder is copied
echo lib folder will be copied
%xcopy% %source%\lib %destination%\%folder%\lib
echo lib folder is copied
echo deploy folder will be copied
%xcopy% %source%\deploy %destination%\%folder%\deploy
echo deploy folder is copied
echo deployers folder will be copied
%xcopy% %source%\deployers %destination%\%folder%\deployers 
echo deplyers folder is copied
echo files will be copy press enter to proceed
pause
```

Comment: What is the question or are you asking for a code review?

Comment: yes i am asking for reviewing the code. and please do suggest any changes to be done.

Comment: In this case you should post your question at http://codereview.stackexchange.com/. This site is not for code review.

Comment: ya i know that and i did the same. but still thanks.